# RSpec error: 'but it does not respond to `include?`'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am running the following rspec test

```
expect(City.first.city_openings('2014-05-01', '2014-05-05')).to include(@listing2,@listing3)
```

I am getting this result

[image]

This is confusing to me because it seems that my result does in fact include the right values. But rspec says that my result "does not respond to include?" Any ideas on how to fix this? I don't see much about it anywhere.

Comment: Some progress! I am getting another error :)  ``Failure/Error: expect(City.first.city_openings('2014-05-01', '2014-05-05')).to match_array([@listing2,@listing3])
       expected a collection that can be converted to an array with `#to_ary` or `#to_a`, but got true``

Comment: [`include`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/include-matcher) is a matcher for anything that has an `include?` method (such as arrays)...looks like `city_openings` might be returning the value `true` instead of an array, judging by the failure message

Comment: Read the error message `City.first.city_openings('2014-05-01', '2014-05-05')` returns `true` and `true` doesn't respond to `include?`. How does the implementation of `city_openings` look like?

Comment: Please, post the error, not a picture of the error. This is a programmer site, [photo.se] is over there.

Comment: @SimpleLime OH! Now I see what is going on. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method city_openings return true and not a array. 
TrueClass is not iterable with include? method.

See the documentation here

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-7/docs/built-in-matchers/match-matcher